# Google Maps API v3: Attach Layer to MapTypeControl

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This might seem like a dumb question, but I can't seem to find an answer.  How do you attach a layer (such as TrafficLayer or a KmlLayer) to the MapTypeControl of a map?

```
  var mapOptions = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.181579, -85.778988),
     zoom: 15
     mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [
           google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
           'Traffic'
        ]
     },
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  var trafLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();

  var trafficMapType = // SCIENCE!

  map.mapTypes.set('Traffic', trafficMapType);
```

What happens in-between?  How do you get the `trafficMapType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the custom controls section of the documentation:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomControls

Comment: Hmmm, so there isn't a way to activate it on the default controls?  Also, I'm guessing that `setMap(map)` and `setMap(null)` will properly add and remove the layer?

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#TrafficLayer

The traffic layer is available as a *layer* rather than a *map type*.  Sample code from the [Google code](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#TrafficLayer) site below:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.04924594193164, -118.24104309082031);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 13,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
trafficLayer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: But, that doesn't answer my question.  I don't want to force the TrafficLayer on the user.  I just want to give them the option to turn on the traffic layer.  Just like how [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/) already provides that option.

Answer (score 0):

For traffic layer I have found the url where there are only traffic features.
This url could be used into a ImageMapType to provide the additional tiles for the principal map type.

This goes as:

```js
var trafficTile = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  name: "Trafico",
  getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom){
    var s = 'Galileo'.substring(0, (3 * coord.x + coord.y ) & 7 ),
      BALANCER = coord.x + coord.y & 1,
      path = [
        "https://mts" + BALANCER + ".googleapis.com/vt?hl=es-419&src=apiv3&lyrs=m@199000000,traffic|seconds_into_week:-1&style=15",
        'z=' + zoom,
        'x=' + coord.x,
        'y=' + coord.y,
        's=' + s
      ]
    ;
    return path.join('&');
  }
});

map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, trafficTile);
```

You maybe want to change the host language (`hl` param) or set custom styles (`apistyle` param)